# printing only first return HttpResponse in django

Tags: python, django

when i use 2 return HTTP Response in views.py in Django it is printing only first return. can anyone help to print the both return in the localhost of Django?

Comment: can you share your code here?

Comment: You can not return two HTTP responses. After you return something, the view ends.

Comment: is there any solution for it?